# Cost of hosting on Google App Engine

Tags: web-hosting, google-workspace

How does the cost of hosting on Google App Engine compare to hosting on more classical servers for a high traffic website?

What's the answer for a website with 1000 page views per minute and how do the costs compare at 10000 page views per minute?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to 'high traffic' ?

Comment: My website isn't build yet, so I unfortunately don't have specific knowledge about how much traffic it will get.

Comment: You _really_ need to define 'high traffic'. Do you expect a hundred page views per minute? One thousand? Ten thousand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it sounds like you're concerned that Google App Engine will work and scale for you, but you're going to get to a point where you exceed their capacity to host you without being costly. Is that right?

I think the thing to do here is to have an "exit strategy" for your App. I think you need this regardless of whether you exceed Google's limits or not. What if Google decides App Engine is a money loser? What if it stops supporting the APIs you want to use?

Check out [**AppScale**](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/), which is intended to be an open source version of Google App Engine for what might end up as your fallback should you outgrow GAE's limits.

Comment: Yes, that seems a good description of my concern. I will look at AppScale.

Answer (score 8):

I was going to post this as a comment but just since you wrote "My website isn't built yet", please take a look at the limits for a free account:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Resources

```
                     Per day            Per minute
Requests             1.3m requests      7,400 requests/minute
Outgoing Bandwidth   1 gb               56 mb/minute
Incoming Bandwidth   1 gb               56 mb/minute
CPU Time             6.5 CPU-hours      16 CPU-seconds/minute
```

If you think you will use a lot more than that, it's one serious web site.

Comment: I think it will be a serious website, that's why I said high traffic.

Comment: I think those limits are about the same as the traffic of stackoverflow.com.

Comment: The bandwidth is kind of skinny, depending on what the site will be serving. That's only 30 GB / average per month down. If its just text and a few images, sure, its plenty.

Comment: @Christian - is the site more likely to be bandwidth intensive, or request intensive, or cpu intensive .. or perhaps a combination of several? You need to give us a little to work with here :)

Comment: @Tim: I think it's probably CPU intensive and it will be hard to cache a lot of the data as it's provided by specific users.

Comment: @Christian: wouldn't it be a wise idea to actually start building the site before worrying about what you'll do if you get 10,000 visitors a day?

Comment: @Kinopiko: Switching off Google App Engine isn't the easiest thing and therefore I think it makes sense to look for whether hosting on Google App Engine makes sense in the long term before committing to it.